# Class not enhanced error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I've been trying to fix this error:

> {"exception":"Persistent class \"Class org.myapp.model.Account does
>   not seem to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and
>   check for errors in the output.\" has no table in the database, but
>   the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the
>   MetaData for this class."}

I've tried cleaning up the project

This is the **Entity** that I'm trying to persist:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Persistent
    private String username;
    @Persistent
    private String password;

    public Account() {

    }
    // Code omitted
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: From the "Enhancer" logs this is the error: NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check two things

Do you have The Entity in "classes to be enhanced list" of eclipse appengine plugin.
Do you have multiple appengine sdk library versions in your classpath.

Comment: BTW, I have installed the Eclipse Datanucleus plugin, do you think that could help?

Comment: I have fixed the error by adding datanucleus-enhancer into the maven POM. However another issue shows up.